# Declaring variable outside the class vs inside

Tags: ios, swift, variables, realm, appdelegate

Hey I am trying to initialise a realm object in my app outside the app delegate.

Now, Since a lot of file in my app are accessing the realm file, i decide to declare it globally.

Now, by doing that I got an app rejection, reasoning crash due to this object. My code is as follows

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

var uiRealm = try! Realm()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

In the above code the object is initialised as the app starts and any other methods loads.

Is it possible that I just declare an object or type Realm and the initialise it under `didFinishLaunching` as follows:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

var uiRealm : Realm!

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // I initialise it here
    uiRealm = try! Realm()
    return true
}
```

Will it make a difference if its declare in such form. I am a little timid about this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S: I already tried declaring the realm variable in app delegate and the calling it in other classes by `UIapplication.shared.delegate`method, and it always crashes.

Comment: Global variables outside of any class are very bad habit (cue *data encapsulation*). A singleton class is preferable. By the way `try!` is also very bad habit unless it's guaranteed that the *trial* succeeds.

Comment: so you suggest the this to put in a singleton class?

Comment: Yes, I do @dexworld

Comment: Thats great and it worked. Could you please write an answer so I can accept it. Many thanks for the prompt response